# Maximal modular ideal

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I met with some troubles with the two concepts:maximal ideal and maximal modular ideal in $C^*$ algebras.

If $I$ is a maximal modular ideal in a $C^*$ algebra $A$,does this imply that for any other proper ideal $J$ in $A$ ,$J$ is contained in $I$,or for any other proper modular ideals $J^\prime$ in $A$ we have $J^\prime\subset I$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the implications hold.  Consider $A=C_0(\mathbb R)$, and $I=\{f\in C_0(\mathbb R)\mid f(0)=0\}$. This is a maximal modular ideal, but it does not contain all other ideals, or all other modular ideals.

Comment: A maximal modular ideal is a modular ideal that is maximal amongst modular ideals.

Comment: The issue is that maximal (modular) ideals need not be unique.  That is, algebras can have plenty of maximal ideals.

Comment: An ideal $I$ in a ring $R$ is maximal if it is proper (i.e. $I\neq R$) and is not properly contained in another proper ideal.  A maximal modular ideal is a modular ideal that is maximal (in the above sense) among modular ideals.  And yes, $S\subset T$.

Comment: No.  If $I$ is a maximal modular ideal of $A$, and $J$ is an ideal of $A$ such that $I\subset J$, then the map $A/I\to A/J$ given by $[a]_I\mapsto [a]_J$ is a surjective $*$-homomorphism, and since $A/I$ is unital (as $I$ is modular), it follows that $A/J$ is unital.  Thus $J$ is modular, and therefore either $J=I$ or $J=A$.